# Missing labeling of menu bar sections in german version of okular

Tags: 18.04, okular, localization

I notice that in the german localisation of *Okular*, some headings in the menu bar are missing, instead they are saying "*Kein Text*" ("no text"), for example the *File* section at the left (it should say *Datei*).

Also, my beloved entry *Recently opened files* is missing. There is not even an *Open* entry in the *File* menu.

[image]

On other computers with Ubuntu 18.04 that I've used, it works. It should look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that for some reason (unknown to me) the menu is overridden by a config file at this address: `.local/share/kxmlgui5/okular/part.rc`.

Solution is to remove the folder and to be in safe margin, instead of removing it, I suggest to rename it by a command like this:

```
mv .local/share/kxmlgui5/okular .local/share/kxmlgui5/okular.bak
```

I had the same issue and this is the result of running the mentioned command:

[image: fix Okular menu]